# Como realizar operaciones entre una columna y una subconsulta

Tags: sql-server, subconsultas

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer operaciones entre una columna y una subconsulta, lo que quiero hacer es sumarle al campo `Subtotal` lo que se obtuvo en la Subconsulta `Impuestos`, el siguiente es el Query que estoy utilizando para este caso.

```
Select 
RC.PURCHID;
LRC.VALUEMST as 'Subtotal',
                  isnull((
                    select sum((CONVERT(float, TD1.taxvalue)/100)*LRC1.VALUEMST ) as a
                           FROM TAXONITEM TOI1
                           inner join TAXDATA TD1 ON (TD1.TAXCODE = TOI1.TAXCODE and RC.DATAAREAID = TD1.DATAAREAID)
                           inner join TRANS LRC1 on (LRC1.VEND = RC.RECID)
                           WHERE TOI1.TAXITEMGROUP = PL.TAXITEMGROUP and RC.DATAAREAID = TOI1.DATAAREAID 
                    ), 0) Impuestos 
       from VEND RC  
             inner join VENDTABLE VTB on VTB.ACCOUNTNUM = RC.INVOICEACCOUNT
             inner join TRANS LRC on (LRC.VEND = RC.RECID)
             inner join PURCHLINE PL on (PL.LINENUMBER =LRC.LINENUM and PL.PURCHID =RC.PURCHID)
             where year (RC.DELIVERYDATE) =2021 and RC.PURCHASETYPE =3 order by RC.PURCHID;
```

Espero que alguien me pueda dar un poco de orientación al realizar operaciones con subconsultas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es mover la subconsulta al `FROM` por medio de un `APPLY` o `JOIN`. De esa forma, el resultado queda como una columna más de la consulta principal.

```
Select  RC.PURCHID,
        LRC.VALUEMST as Subtotal,
        isnull(I.Impuestos, 0) AS Impuestos,
        LRC.VALUEMST + isnull(I.Impuestos, 0) AS Total
from       VEND      RC  
inner join VENDTABLE VTB on VTB.ACCOUNTNUM = RC.INVOICEACCOUNT
inner join TRANS     LRC on LRC.VEND       = RC.RECID
inner join PURCHLINE PL  on PL.LINENUMBER  = LRC.LINENUM 
                        and PL.PURCHID     = RC.PURCHID
CROSS APPLY (select     sum((CONVERT(float, TD1.taxvalue)/100) * LRC1.VALUEMST ) as Impuestos
             FROM       TAXONITEM TOI1
             inner join TAXDATA   TD1  ON TD1.TAXCODE   = TOI1.TAXCODE 
                                      and RC.DATAAREAID = TD1.DATAAREAID
             inner join TRANS     LRC1 on LRC1.VEND     = RC.RECID
             WHERE TOI1.TAXITEMGROUP = PL.TAXITEMGROUP 
             and   TOI1.DATAAREAID   = RC.DATAAREAID) I
where RC.DELIVERYDATE >= '20210101'
AND   RC.DELIVERYDATE <  '20220101'
and RC.PURCHASETYPE = 3 
order by RC.PURCHID;

Select  RC.PURCHID,
        LRC.VALUEMST as Subtotal,
        isnull(I.Impuestos, 0) AS Impuestos,
        LRC.VALUEMST + isnull(I.Impuestos, 0) AS Total
from       VEND      RC  
inner join VENDTABLE VTB on VTB.ACCOUNTNUM = RC.INVOICEACCOUNT
inner join TRANS     LRC on LRC.VEND       = RC.RECID
inner join PURCHLINE PL  on PL.LINENUMBER  = LRC.LINENUM 
                        and PL.PURCHID     = RC.PURCHID
LEFT JOIN  (select  TOI1.TAXITEMGROUP,
                    TOI1.DATAAREAID,
                    sum((CONVERT(float, TD1.taxvalue)/100) * LRC1.VALUEMST ) as Impuestos
             FROM       TAXONITEM TOI1
             inner join TAXDATA   TD1  ON TD1.TAXCODE   = TOI1.TAXCODE 
                                      and RC.DATAAREAID = TD1.DATAAREAID
             inner join TRANS     LRC1 on LRC1.VEND     = RC.RECID) I ON I.TAXITEMGROUP = PL.TAXITEMGROUP 
                                                                     and I.DATAAREAID   = RC.DATAAREAID
where RC.DELIVERYDATE >= '20210101'
AND   RC.DELIVERYDATE <  '20220101'
and   RC.PURCHASETYPE = 3 
order by RC.PURCHID;
```